# How to get default binding mode of a control property in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I understand that if a property of a control is user editable, then it will support two way binding mode. e.g. TextBox.Text property can be get and set as well.

So, my question is how [to look programmatically/designer property window] to get default mode of a control's property. i.e. For TextBox.Text, default binding mode is two way itself, not the oneway, onewaytosource, or onetime.

I hope, I am clear to my question. Please ask me, if it is not clear.

Answer (score 5):

```
TextBox text = new TextBox();

...

// Set your binding
...

// Get the binding
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(text, TextBox.TextProperty);

if (binding != null)
{
   // Get the mode
   BindingMode mode = binding.Mode;
}
```

Comment: @Nick-what is text here?

Comment: Getting NullReferenceException on 2nd statement.

Comment: My example assumes you set the binding somewhere.  If the TextBox doesn't have a binding, then the BindingOperations.GetBinding(text, TextBox.TextProperty) will return null.  Edited again...

Comment: @Nick-Thanks. It worked now. Do you now, if we have any option of understanding default property binding mode directly in Designer Property window?